# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x9f' in position 47: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, xml, unicode

Below is the code that is supposed to convert bz2 to text format. However; I am getting a unicode error.Since I am using utf-8 I wonder what the error could be

```py
from __future__ import print_function

import logging
import os.path
import six
import sys

from gensim.corpora import WikiCorpus

if __name__ == '__main__':
    program = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
    logger = logging.getLogger(program)

    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    logging.root.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)
    logger.info("running %s" % ' '.join(sys.argv))

    # check and process input arguments

    inp =  "trwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2"
    outp = "wiki_text_dump.txt"
    space = " "
    i = 0

    output = open(outp, 'w')
    wiki = WikiCorpus(inp, lemmatize=False, dictionary={})
    for text in wiki.get_texts():
        if six.PY3:
            output.write(' '.join(text).encode().decode('unicode_escape') + '\n')
        #   ###another method###
        #    output.write(
        #            space.join(map(lambda x:x.decode("utf-8"), text)) + '\n')
        else:
            output.write(space.join(text) + "\n")
            #output.write(text)
        i = i + 1
        if (i % 10000 == 0):
            logger.info("Saved " + str(i) + " articles")

    output.close()
    logger.info("Finished Saved " + str(i) + " articles")
```

Error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-9404745af31b> in <module>()
     32     for text in wiki.get_texts():
     33         if six.PY3:
---> 34             output.write(' '.join(text).encode().decode('unicode_escape') + '\n')
     35         #   ###another method###
     36         #    output.write(

c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\encodings\cp1254.py in encode(self, input, final)
     17 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
     18     def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
     20 
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x9f' in position 47: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've also replaced "unicode_escape" with "utf-8" then I get this error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 87-92: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the traceback indicates, the error occurs during the call to `.encode`, *not* during the call to `.decode`. Therefore you cannot fix the problem by changing the `.decode` codec.

Since the code is running in Python 3.x (`six.PY3` is true - but why are you concerned with 2.x compatibility in new code written today?), and since `' '.join(text)` worked, we conclude that `text` is either a string or a list of strings (not a `bytes` or list of `bytes`), and `' '.join(text)` is a string. Indeed, the [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/wikicorpus.html#gensim.corpora.wikicorpus.WikiCorpus.get_texts) tells us that `WikiCorpus` will already provide strings.

This string contains some character that your codec, `cp1254.py` (this is a Windows code page specially intended for Turkish text), cannot encode. It is not clear to me what you hope to accomplish by encoding and then decoding again. Just use the string. In fact, `text` should already be a single string that does not need any `.join`ing (unless you wanted to put a space after each letter, for some reason). You should verify this for yourself by debugging.

Comment: text is a list consisting of multiple strings. I tried output.write(text) but that didn't work either. Can you elaborate your answer on my code. I have copied this code from https://textminingonline.com/training-word2vec-model-on-english-wikipedia-by-gensim. I can't comprehend all about it :/

Comment: when I use output.write(text) I get the error "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list.".

Comment: I think the exception is raised not by the `.encode()` call, but rather by the implicit encoding process that is triggered when you call the `.write()` method of a `TextIOWrapper` object (which is what you get from `open()`). I agree that `.encode().decode()` is pointless and should be removed, but it probably won't solve the issue here. What is missing here is the `encoding="utf8"` parameter in the `open()` call.

Comment: The reason is: `str.encode()` defaults to UTF-8, but `open()` has a platform-dependent default (the codec depends on the locale and stuff).

Comment: `when I use output.write(text) I get the error "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list."` Yes, exactly as it says: you have a *list of* strings, not a single string. You write individual strings to a file; thus you must iterate and write each string from the list separately.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I removed six.PY3 part and it worked thank you !